# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I created an email using Xcode 7.3 beta 3 .. I go the code from [appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-send-email-iphone-app/)

```
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {
    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"iOS programming is so fun!";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@appcoda.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

But it gave me an error (as you can see below) after running the application on iPhone

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target .'*** First throw call stack:()libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: when you get this error for e.g if you press the button of `showEmail:(id)sender` this or some where else

Comment: I don't really understand, can you explain it more?

Comment: when u get the error `Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target -- It means you try to implement the nil objcet on target check once if it is nil or not

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
if (!mc) {  
  //When the device has not added mailViewController mail account is empty , the following present view controller causes the program to crash here
NSLog(@"no email accounts are set up in your device");  
return;  
}
```

sample [tutorial](http://blog.csdn.net/jymn_chen/article/details/19253433)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**

Use if let

```
if let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController() {
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
    mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
    self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Using the related `MFMessageComposeViewController`, I get this too. (Xcode 10, Swift 4.2). What is baffling, when you create the VC, if you wait long enough (you pretty much have to comment out the `present` line, MF will do the service detection and show its own alert saying: "Cannot send message".